# Strange scaling in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d

I'm trying to stretch a sprite to screen bounds uniformly.
First I set the origin of the sprite to the centre of the screen. Since it's an Android device, I have several pages to scroll through to reach the end. In my experience, width*2 covers the extra distance.

```
mSprite.setOrigin(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
//these return 1080 and 960 on my device
```

Next I set the sprite's X and Y relative to the origin:

```
mSprite.setPosition(mSprite.getOriginX()-mSprite.getWidth()/2, mSprite.getOriginY()-mSprite.getHeight()/2);
//sprite width and height are 1440 and 1280
```

Now draw it with `mSprite.draw(batch)`

[image: left][image: right]

To a naked eye, it doesn't look off. Having measured the distance, there is no difference.

Now I apply a scale:

```
mSprite.setScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
```

Result:

[image: left][image: right]

As you can see, after scaling, the sprite no longer appears to be in the centre.

Why? What am I doing wrong? If this is how it's supposed to work, can anyone please recommend a viable workaround to uniformly scale a sprite?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the whole screen coordinates to set the origin of the sprite you should use sprites width and height:

```
mSprite.setOrigin(mSprite.getWidth()/2f, mSprite.getHeight()/2f);
```

Sprites use separate coordinate system that has (0,0) at the bottom left corner of the sprite .

Since sprite's origin doesn't effect the way you set your position ( It will always be in bottom left corner)

Set position to the middle:

```
mSprite.setPosition(screenWidth/2f-mSprite.getWidth/2f,screenHeight/2f - mSprite.getHeight/2f);
```

This also assumes that your camera is at position (screenWidth/2f,screenHeight/2f).

If your camera isn't looking at (screenWidth/2f,screenHeight/2f) and instead is positioned at (0,0) then set sprite's position like this:

```
mSprite.setPosition(-mSprite.getWidth/2f, - mSprite.getHeight/2f);
```

Comment: That's because I want it to be drawn in the middle of the screen. I want to scale it so it fills the screen. Since scaling is done around the origin, it has to be in the middle of the screen.
I tried your suggestion (without scale) and it placed the black rectangle in the bottom left corner. After I scaled it, it expanded further in the top right. The loss of detail is not noticeable because it's just a black rectangle. But if it's a proper background, after scaling, the bottom left will not be visible as it will expand outside the screen.

Comment: Setting sprites origin to the screens origin won't actually set sprites origin in the middle. Instead it would probably set it somewhere out of screen (just guessing I don't know the size of the sprite or the screen). You are missing a point here. I will edit my answer.